# .Net StompClient through websockets

Tags: c#, .net, spring, activemq-classic, stomp

We have an (Java) Spring Application that uses Stomp and websockets with our browser client application. It uses basic authentication to validate use and password.

We also have an C# application that comunicates with the same server (SOAP) and now we are trying to show some realtime data for those client too. Is there a way to connect a C# application though websockets and stomp?

The spring is a relay for a ActiveMQ broker inside our server, but it could have some business rules. Also, I do not think it is a good idea put our broker opened for the internet.

Comment: Any success on finding a suitable library for the client? We're having the save issue.

Comment: Nope, we decided to create our own since the protocol is not very complicated. We are using websocket# for connections and handling messages using ultralight serialization/deserialization.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ultralight/

Comment: If you need some help, just make a call

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a library to implement STOMP over websocket client side i suggest you this: https://github.com/huhuhong/websocket-csharp-net-stomp-client

Answer (score -4):

The ActiveMQ WebSocket transport supports STOMP, MQTT and AMQP 1.0 so if you use a .NET client library that can handle STOMP and WebSockets then all you need to do is ensure that your broker has the WebSocket transport configured in.

Comment: Tim, I wasn´t clear: I am seeking a .Net client library that handle STOMP over Websockets. The server side is not an issue.

Comment: Then your question is not really valid for SO, off site resources aren't really a topic that's valid here, there are search engines for such things.  I don't know of any .NET STOMP clients that support WS but that doesn't mean there aren't any.